# Best way of implementing custom UI objects jawa.awt.Graphics

Tags: java, graphics

What is the best way to implement custom sliders (for volume), buttons normal, with images (icons) and with text, text boxes and other stuff with java.awt.Graphics?

Thanks,
Kerdo

Answer (score 2):

This is easy.
First you have to capture the click and move events:

```
addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
    @Override void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        mouse(e)
    }
...
```

And you travel through all the `button`s, `slide`s, etc.. in the `mouse` method, to pass the location of the mouse to them:

```
public void mouse(MouseEvent e) {
    allComponents.forEach(a -> a.hey(e.getX(), e.getY()));
}
```

And then you update the states in the `hey` method. For example, if it's a button, you see if the location of the mouse is inside the button. If so, you set your `button`'s color to a darker one (just for example).

Then draw all the game objects to the screen. Override the `paintComponent` method, and invoke the methods of the parameter `Graphics g`, like `drawString`, `drawRect`, etc..

The approach described above is used in [one of my personal project](https://github.com/icela/FriceEngine).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I followed some tutorials and now got some things still to ask:
I'm switching between gamestates (main menu, pause menu, etc). When switching the old menu's ui components are still accessible (clickable, executable). So I wrote a simple UI Manager to update all the components simultaneously. Now I'm creating a new UI Manager for every state and have to switch it in mousemanager. Is it better to have one and have tags on uicomponents to tell which state they belong in and update them when the corresponding menu is active? Mousemanager: (1/2)

Comment: Some screencaps of my code: https://imgur.com/XRWA1XB (MouseManager), https://imgur.com/a/YsHXt (Main menu UI implementation), https://imgur.com/a/qQDWm (UIManager). Any comments of making it better? (2/2)

Comment: You can `g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height)` before every refresh

Comment: A suggestion: `for (A a : as) { if (!a.x()) continue; a.y(); }` can be replaced with `for (A a : as) { if (a.x()) a.y(); }` :D

Comment: Actually I'm not familiar with the API you used so I can't be helpful with the usage of the widgets :) (BTW you have 16 rep now and you can upvote my answer :)

Comment: Can I see your drawing code? Maybe your way of drawing the widgets is wrong. You may ask a new question and send me the link, since it's a different topic

Comment: I'm only using pure Java. Here's my drawing code in my main gameloop: https://imgur.com/r2SgDxz

Comment: So I got it working like it should. Added a line in MenuManager's setmenu function that sets the currently selected UI Manager (that the MouseManager uses to send over mousepresses) to the selected menu's ones.

Comment: Still two questions:
1) How do I make sliders? How do I make them follow the mouse? I have to set the selection point of the bounds and move it by how much the mouse moves or something?

2) When holding mouse1 (in game) and moving the mouse at the same time the mouse x and y still update but I'm drawing a line from the player to the mouse x and y, the line stays still and so do the bullets.